# Jasper Reports HTML Component

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have Designed a simple report putting and HTML palette into it (iFrame)
When I run the report i get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.components.html.HtmlComponent
```

I check the rar file and there is no net.sf.jasperreports.components.html.HtmlComponent class in it.

What do i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the HTML Component's Jar.
The JAR can be built from the `/demo/samples/htmlcomponent` either using the >ant jar command. You can also grab the jar from the Jaspersoft Studio download. Just search for the `htmlcomponent.jar` once you've downloaded it.