# Jasper reports HtmlComponent class not found

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have designed a simple report by putting HTML palette using iReport. When I run the report i get this exception:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.components.html.HtmlComponent from [Module "deployment.myProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

I am using this code.

```
InputStream is;
JasperReport jReport = null;
JasperPrint jPrint = null;

if (Utils.isEmpty(dataList)) {
    throw new Exception("No data to fill");
}

try {
    is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/templates/jr/myfile.jasper");
    if (is != null) {
        jReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);
    }
    if (jReport != null) {
        if ("JDBC".equalsIgnoreCase(dataSrc)) {
            Connection con = ((DataSource) (new InitialContext().lookup(""))).getConnection();
            jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, params, con);
        } else if ("JAVABEAN".equalsIgnoreCase(dataSrc)) {
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
            jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, params, jrDataSource);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    throw new Exception("Error generating JR Template:" + templateName, e);
}
```

I got exception in this line :

```
jReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);
```

I have checked the jasperReports.jar and found that there is no htmlComponent class. I also use latest version of jasperReport library(i.e 6.1.0) and there is no net.sf.jasperreports.components. html.HtmlComponent class in it. Anyone please help me how to include them into my project with netbeans ???

**EDIT 1 :** I have included the htmlComponent jar into my maven web project as dependency in pom.xml file using this code:

```
     <dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
     <artifactId>htmlcomponent</artifactId>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/htmlcomponent.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
```

Now my dependency structure looks like this:

[image]

You can see the htmlComponent dependency contains the net.sf.jasperreports.components.html.HtmlComponent class. But i am still getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: please show you jrxml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added following dependency into pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>htmlComponent</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlComponent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then install 3rd party jar in project by following command as describe in this link [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

i.e

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=htmlcomponent.jar -DgroupId=htmlComponent -DartifactId=htmlComponent -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar.

and then build the project and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add htmlcomponent.jar

Check this for building [htmlcomponent.jar](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/html-component-errors-jasper-server-and-ireport)

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213529/jasper-reports-html-component).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created the htmlComponent.jar and include it in my project . My project is maven web project. So i include this jar file from local system as dependency in pom.xml file. code is : <dependency>
         <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
         <artifactId>htmlcomponent</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}/src/lib/htmlcomponent.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>             and htmlComponent is successfully added as dependency in my project .But i still getting the same exception.

Comment: tried Maven->Update Project and clean project and re-launch the application from the IDE?

Comment: change dependency scope from <scope>provided</scope> to <scope>compile</scope> and give it a try

Comment: check http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: I am using <scope>system</scope> because i use htmlComponent.jar from my local system. See my dependency code .Please update if i did wrong in that code. I refrred this tutorial for adding external dependency http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm

Comment: this might http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html help you

Comment: thanks for these links i tried that but i need repository from which to download jar. For eg <repository>
            <id></id>
            <url>http://</url>
        </repository> .Any idea of repository.

Comment: An artifact you mention in pom is actually downloaded from repository. If you are using eclipse maven then it probably inside /Users/<username>/.m2 if you want to explicit go to a certain repository you use the mentioned <repository> tags. refer http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/